# Cypher how to MERGE without re-creating existing nodes

Tags: merge, neo4j, cypher

I have to update some properties on en entity (we extracted some user properties to a separate entity). Now I'm trying to write a query that updates the existing data.
This is what I have so far:

```
// Match the user and it's settings
MATCH (s:UserSettings)-[:SETTINGS_FROM]->(u:User)

// Set the properties of the settings node to their old value from user entity
SET s.`settings.key1` = u.key1
SET s.`settings.key2` = u.key2
SET s.`settings.key3` = u.key3

// Remove the keys on the user entity
SET u.key1 = null
SET u.key2 = null
SET u.key3 = null

RETURN s, u;
```

This works for users that already have a `UserSettings` node attached, but not for users without.
I tried to replace `MATCH` with `MERGE` - this will create a new user although all users are available in the db. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `MERGE` on a path means that if **any** of the path elements is missing, the whole pattern will be created.
Usually, you want to `MERGE` specific nodes and relationships, not a whole path at once.

Assuming:

1. the user nodes are always present
2. the settings nodes are always created at the same time as their `SETTINGS_FROM` relationship (otherwise, you'd have to `MERGE` first on the settings node pattern AND then on the relationship)

You should run something like:

```
MATCH (u:User)
MERGE (s:UserSettings)-[:SETTINGS_FROM]->(u)
ON CREATE
   SET s.`settings.key1` = u.key1
   SET s.`settings.key2` = u.key2
   SET s.`settings.key3` = u.key3
REMOVE u.key1 // those removes are not part of ON CREATE (see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/6172)
REMOVE u.key2
REMOVE u.key3
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation. This 100% does what I need.
Being new to graph databases I have a bit of a hard time understanding such stuff with just the docs...